# SpringMVC-Angularjs: how can I change the content-type in SpringMVC?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

When I use the Angularjs to send a data to SpringMVC, SpringMVC can't get the data,it's 400,or null object.

So,I try to see the console information in browser,I find a difference between RequestHeaders and ResponseHeaders,I show it as follows:

```
    response headers

    Connection:close
    Content-Language:en
    Content-Length:1105

    Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8

    Date:Mon, 25 Apr 2016 13:52:07 GMT
    Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
    Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1


    Request Headers
    view source
    Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, lzma
    Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:50
    Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Cookie:JSESSIONID=21DCE26028722FE4C396D8CA3D6FC4C4
```

I try to change the springMVC's responseheaders, but it changes nothing, still   like that.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveNewUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public String saveRegisterInfo(@RequestParam("user") User user) {


 //I can't get user here. When I use @RequestBody, user is null. 
 //When I use @RequestParam, it's error 400 or 415.
 //these days I try to learn Angularjs,I think the type of data make me crazy,just like contentType, json

    System.out.println(user);

    //      User u = userServive.saveRegisterUser(user);
    if (user != null) {
        return "1";

    } else {

        return "0";
    }
}
```

How can I change the conent-type from "text/html;charset=utf-8" to "application/json, text/plain" for response-headers?

Answer (score 0):

Two steps would help you;

Add Jackson Mapper Asl to your project's dependencies

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>  
  <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>  
  <version>1.9.10</version>  
</dependency>
```

Add `@ResponseBody` annotation to your controller

Then your controller will response JSON objects.

Comment: Is it different from jackson-databind,jackson-core and jackson-annotation?

Comment: I think it's better to use Jackson 2.x version. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: It doesn't matter.